# jQuery UI not working inside javaScript function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

`function newbox(Title, Messagetext) {
              $(document).ready(function () {
                  $("#div1").text(Messagetext);
                  $("#div1").dialog({
                      modal: true,
                      title: Title,
                      buttons: {
                          Ok: function () {
                              enbleButton();
                              $(this).dialog("close");
                              //self.close();
                          }
                      }
                  });
              });
          }`
given newBox function is used to show modal popup. this function totally fine if called inside $(document).ready() like this

`$(document).ready(function () {
  newbox('test', 'niraj');
  });`
but doesn't work when i call it through javascript function like :

```
 function test()  
{
    $(document).ready(function () {
        newbox('test', 'niraj');
    });  
    return false;
```

}
im using IE8, jQuery 1.10.2 and jQuery UI 1.11.4

Update:

My HTML:

```
<div style="display:none;">
<div id="dialog-message">
    test text
</div>
<div id="div1">
    test text
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove dom ready event from that code, then it will work fine.
Because, `$(document).ready()` is an event, not a function. That event will occur at the page loading. When you call that function, the event may already have completed, if so this code will not execute.

Try,

```
function newbox(Title, Messagetext) {
    $("#div1").text(Messagetext);
    $("#div1").dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: Title,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function() {
                enbleButton();
                $(this).dialog("close");
                //self.close();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$(document).ready() is for when the page loads. Don't put it inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

`$(document).ready(callback)` attaches an event to document which is triggered when the readyState of document changes to **complete**(few other conditions too). You attach this event inside a function `test()`, what happens is when you call this function then the eventListener gets attached to document but as document is already loaded the callback doesn't take place:

Suggested Code:

```
function test()  
{
        newbox('test', 'niraj');

    return false;  
}
```

and

```
function newbox(Title, Messagetext) {
                  $("#div1").text(Messagetext);
                  $("#div1").dialog({
                      modal: true,
                      title: Title,
                      buttons: {
                          Ok: function () {
                              enbleButton();
                              $(this).dialog("close");
                              //self.close();
                          }
                      }
                  });
          }
```

and to make it work in IE8 your HTML div `#div1` should not be self-closing.

Comment: Could you post your html code that is `#div1`, it should not be self-closing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185779/ie8-not-working-with-jquery-dialog

Comment: it is not self closing..    <div style="display:none;">
        <div id="dialog-message">
            test text
        </div>
        <div id="div1">
            test text
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: have you tried removing `return false` from function test?

Comment: How are you calling the test function?At what event?

Comment: yes i tried removing the 'return false '..but it didn't work. And I'm using Scriptmanager.RegisterStartupScript() in c# to call test() function